# Question on boost::swap

Tags: c++, boost

Couple of questions on `boost::swap`. Please refer to the code below which is basically a cut-paste from `boost/swap.hpp`. I am referring to library version 1.43.0.

```
namespace boost_swap_impl
    {
      template<class T>
      void swap_impl(T& left, T& right)
      {
        using namespace std;//use std::swap if argument dependent lookup fails
        swap(left,right);
      }

  template<class T, std::size_t N>
  void swap_impl(T (& left)[N], T (& right)[N])
  {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
      ::boost_swap_impl::swap_impl(left[i], right[i]);
    }
  }
}

namespace boost
{
  template<class T1, class T2>
  void swap(T1& left, T2& right)
  {
    ::boost_swap_impl::swap_impl(left, right);
  }
}
```

1. Why is `boost::swap` declared as `template <typename T1, typename T2>` when in the rest of the code it is all dealing with the same type?
2. If I define my own global function `void swap(T&, T&)` I see that it is the global function that gets called from `swap_impl(T& left, T& right)`. Is this not a conflict and hence an error condition since `swap_impl` also uses `namespace std` which has swap defined?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. This makes it less specialized than `std::swap` so you don't get overload ambiguity errors when both `std::swap` and `boost::swap` are in scope (`std::swap` will take precedence).
2. No, non-templates always have precedence over templates during overload resolution, so a namespace-scoped non-template `swap` will take precedence over both `boost::swap` and `std::swap` (as will a namespace-scoped template `swap` overloaded for a UDT – think partially-specialized, but not really..). Note that unlike `std::swap`, `boost::swap` is written explicitly to take advantage of [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup).

Here's what the C++03 standard has to say regarding both points – [over.match.best] (§13.3.3/1):

> Define ICS*i*(`F`) as follows:
>
> - if `F` is a static member function, ICS*1*(`F`) is defined such that ICS*1*(`F`) is neither better nor worse than ICS*1*(`G`) for any function `G`, and, symmetrically, ICS*1*(`G`) is neither better nor worse than ICS*1*(`F`); otherwise,
> - let ICS*i*(`F`) denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts the *i*-th argument in the list to the type of the *i*-th parameter of viable function `F`. 13.3.3.1 defines the implicit conversion sequences and 13.3.3.2 defines what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than another.
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a *better* function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments *i*, ICS*i*(`F1`) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS*i*(`F2`), and then
>
> - for some argument *j*, ICS*j*(`F1`) is a better conversion sequence than ICS*j*(`F2`), or, if not that,
> - `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization, or, if not that,
> - `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.5.2, or, if not that,
> - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F1` to the destination type (i.e., the type of the entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F2` to the destination type.

Comment: @jam: +1. Could you please point me to the C++ reference standard section which talks about the precedence of non-template over template code?

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm afraid your note is [under contention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170247/does-c11-change-the-behavior-of-explicitly-calling-stdswap-to-ensure-adl-loc). I thought it was the case as well, but perhaps not.

Comment: @GMan : Thanks for the heads up. :-] I'll edit my answer accordingly after your question is answered. It's certainly a shame, though, if you're right and C++11 doesn't address this as Boost does, especially considering how trivial the implementation is.

Comment: But why `using namespace std;` instead of `using std::swap;`?

Comment: @ildjarn Can you update your answer to elaborate? It is new to me that using declarations and using directives are different regarding ADL.

Comment: @L.F. : It doesn't really relate to the questions though, which were quite specific. ;-] There are plenty of existing questions on that topic like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49312461/636019) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27544893/636019).