# Does C++11 change the behavior of explicitly calling std::swap to ensure ADL-located swap's are found, like boost::swap?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, swap

#### Background

Consider the following code:

```
#include <utility>

namespace ns
{
    struct foo
    {
        foo() : i(0) {}
        int i;
        
    private:
        foo(const foo&); // not defined,
        foo& operator=(const foo&); // non-copyable
    };
    
    void swap(foo& lhs, foo& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(lhs.i, rhs.i);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void do_swap(T& lhs, T& rhs); // implementation to be determined

int main()
{
    ns::foo a, b;
    do_swap(a, b);
}
```

In C++03, this implementation of `do_swap` would be considered "broken":

```
template <typename T>
void do_swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
{
    std::swap(lhs, rhs);
}
```

By explicitly specifying `std::`, it prohibits `ns::swap` from being found via argument-dependent lookup. (It then fails to compile because `std::swap` tries to copy a `foo`, which is not allowed.) Instead, we do this:

```
template <typename T>
void do_swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
{
    using std::swap; // allow std::swap as a backup if ADL fails to find a swap
    swap(lhs, rhs); // unqualified call to swap, allow ADL to operate
}
```

Now `ns::swap` is found and `std::swap`, being less specialized, is not used. It's uglier, but it works and is understandable in hind-sight. `boost::swap` wraps this up nicely for us (and provides array overloads):

```
#include <boost/swap.hpp>

template <typename T>
void do_swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
{
    boost::swap(lhs, rhs); // internally does what do_swap did above
}
```

#### Question

Does `std::swap` take on the behavior of `boost::swap` in C++11? If not, why?

To me it seems obvious that it ought to. Any code broken by the change was probably quite flimsy in the first place (algorithms and containers, like `std::sort` and `std::vector`, were underspecified; implementations were allowed to call ADL swap's or not indeterminately), so the change would be for the better. Additionally, `std::swap` is now defined for arrays, so change at all certainly isn't out of the question.

However, while §17.6.3.2 specifies that all calls to `swap` within the standard library must be done without `std::` qualification (fixing the problem with algorithms and containers noted above), it fails to touch on `std::swap` itself. It even gives examples of swapping values that include `using std::swap;`. Likewise §20.2.2 (where `std::swap` is specified) doesn't say a word on ADL.

Lastly, GCC does not enable ADL in their `std::swap` implementation (nor does MSVC, but that's not saying much). So I must be wrong that `std::swap` takes on the behavior of `boost::swap`, but I don't understand why the change wasn't made. :( [And I'm not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115281/87234)!

Comment: I also remember always hearing that C++11's `std::swap` should use ADL, strange.

Comment: Does anything here depend on koenig lookup rules if the items being swapped are in a namespace? Of course you can always overload swap for any specific type as swap is a template so your overload will always take precedence over the general template, eg void swap(MyT&a, MyT&b) { a.swap(b); }

Comment: @CashCow: You mean specialize in the `std` namespace? That works some of the time (can't partially specialize functions, so no template classes), but it's clumsy and goes against good design.

Comment: Howard Hinnant's answer below gives a great counterexample. However, be aware that Eric Niebler (at least) has proposed that `std::swap` (or something much like it) *should* behave the way you want. See ["Customization Point Design in C++11 and Beyond"](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/) (Oct 2014 blog post) and [N4381 Suggested Design for Customization Points](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4381.html) which was discussed at Lenexa in May 2015.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would have had to vote against your proof-of-concept implementation had it been proposed.  I fear it would break the following code, which I'm pretty sure I've seen in the wild at least once or twice over the past dozen years.

```
namespace oops
{

    struct foo
    {
        foo() : i(0) {}
        int i;

        void swap(foo& x) {std::swap(*this, x);}
    };

    void swap(foo& lhs, foo& rhs)
    {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }

}
```

Whether you think the above is good code or bad, it works as the author intends in C++98/03 and so the bar for silently breaking it is pretty high.  Telling users that in C++11 they would no longer have to write `using std::swap;` isn't a sufficiently high benefit to outweigh the disadvantage of silently turning the above code into infinite recursion.

Another way to get out of writing `using std::swap;` is to use `std::iter_swap` instead:

```
template <typename T>
void do_swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
{
    std::iter_swap(&lhs, &rhs); // internally does what do_swap did above
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In C++20, this is finally standardized:

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

This uses ADL to call the correct overload and imposes the correct requirements to use in SFINAE.  The magic is specified in [[namespace.std]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#7):

> Other than in namespace `std` or in a namespace within namespace
>   `std`, a program may provide an overload for any library function
>   template designated as a *customization point*, provided that (a) the
>   overload's declaration depends on at least one user-defined type and
>   (b) the overload meets the standard library requirements for the
>   customization point.<sup>174</sup> [ *Note:* **This permits a
>   (qualified or unqualified) call to the customization point to invoke
>   the most appropriate overload for the given arguments.** — *end
>   note* ]
>
> <sup><sup>174)</sup> Any library customization point must be prepared
>   to work adequately with any user-defined overload that meets the
>   minimum requirements of this document. Therefore an implementation may
>   elect, under the as-if rule ([intro.execution]), to provide any
>   customization point in the form of an instantiated function object
>   ([function.objects]) even though the customization point's
>   specification is in the form of a function template. The template
>   parameters of each such function object and the function parameters
>   and return type of the object's `operator()` must match those of the
>   corresponding customization point's specification.</sup>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

And `swap` is designated as a customization point in [[utility.swap]](http://eel.is/c++draft/utility.swap):

> ```
> template<class T>
>   constexpr void swap(T& a, T& b) noexcept(see below);
> ```
>
> *Remarks:* **This function is a designated customization point** ([namespace.std]) and shall not participate in overload resolution
>   unless `is_­move_­constructible_­v<T>` is `true` and
>   `is_­move_­assignable_­v<T>` is `true`. The expression inside
>   `noexcept` is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T> && is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T>
> ```
>
> *Requires:* Type `T` shall be *Cpp17MoveConstructible* (Table 26) and *Cpp17MoveAssignable* (Table 28).
>
> *Effects:* Exchanges values stored in two locations.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: So how does this interact with code like the example in Howard's answer?

Comment: @aschepler *silently turning the above code into infinite recursion* :(

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proof-of-concept implementation:

```
#include <utility>

// exposition implementation
namespace std_
{
    namespace detail
    {
        // actual fallback implementation
        template <typename T>
        void swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
        {
            T temp = std::move(lhs);
            lhs = std::move(rhs);
            rhs = std::move(temp);
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    void swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
    {
        using detail::swap; // shadows std_::swap, stops recursion
        swap(lhs, rhs); // unqualified call, allows ADL
    }
}

namespace ns
{
    struct foo
    {
        foo() : i(0) {}
        int i;

    private:
        foo(const foo&); // not defined,
        foo& operator=(const foo&); // non-copyable
    };

    void swap(foo& lhs, foo& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(lhs.i, rhs.i);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    std_::swap(i, j);

    ns::foo a, b;
    std_::swap(a, b);
}
```

Comment: (Note that even if it weren't possible in C++ alone, the standard library implementation is allowed to use compiler magic, including changing the rules for ADL in the case of `std::swap` manually.)

Comment: You might want to mention that this works only if every single type in `std` (or `std_` in this case) has a custom `swap`, since the shadowing wont work for those types (`std::swap` (or `std_::swap` here) is found via ADL in that case). But of course that (or compiler magic) would be a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `boost::swap()` dispatches to `std::swap()`. To have `std::swap()` do something similar to `boost::swap()` it would need to delegate somewhere else. What is this somewhere else? The standard doesn't mandate another version of `swap()` which provides the actual implementation. This can be done but the standard doesn't mandate it.

Why it doesn't do it? I didn't see any proposal proposing this implementation. If someone had wanted this to do done I'm sure it would have been proposed.

Comment: I  don't disagree with anything you've said, but I'm also not quite sure what you're saying. It could be done but it wasn't because nobody proposed it? I haven't looked through the proposals, but I'd be quite surprised if this wasn't brought up.

Comment: Admittedly, I only searched for proposals with "swap" in their titles and the only documents I located are N2590 (Simplifying `swap` overloads), N3103 (Small-string optimization not possible with current swap() specification), and N3179 (Move and swap for I/O streams). None of them talks about using ADL in the implementation of `std::swap()`. Surprise...! I don't think it was brought up. Did you bring it up?

Comment: No I didn't, I wasn't aware of the standardization process in time to do so. Well if it really just wasn't brought up, that's quite disappointing. It's less than a stones throw away from what *was* brought up.