# use boost::swap to swap raw pointers?

Tags: c++, boost

Based on [pp. 8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321133544)

> Free Functions
>
> ```
> template<typename T> void swap(scoped_ptr<T>& a,scoped_ptr<T>& b)
> ```
>
> This function offers the preferred means by which to exchange the
>   contents of two scoped pointers. It is preferable because
>   swap(scoped1,scoped2) can be applied generically (in templated code)
>   to many pointer types, including raw pointers and third-party smart
>   pointers.[2] scoped1.swap(scoped2) only works on smart pointers, not
>   on raw pointers, and only on those that define the operation.

```
int* pA = new int(10);
int *pB = new int(20);

boost::swap(pA, pB); // Error: could not deduce template argument for 'boost::scoped_ptr<T> &' from 'int *'
```

**Question**> How to swap raw pointers with `boost::swap`?

Comment: Is the code snippet yours or from the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why the other answers are telling you not to use `boost::swap`. The *entire purpose* of `boost::swap` is to hide the `using std::swap; swap(x, y);` business. This works just fine:

```
#include <boost/swap.hpp>

int main()
{
    int* pA = new int(10);
    int *pB = new int(20);

    boost::swap(pA, pB);

    delete pA;
    delete pB;
}
```

Obviously if you haven't included `boost/swap.hpp` this won't work. That's how you use `boost::swap` to swap two things. You should always prefer to swap two things in this form!

What you're reading is simply stating that `boost::scoped_ptr` also provides an overload of `swap` inside the `boost` namespace, so that this works too:

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

int main()
{    
    boost::scoped_ptr<int> pA(new int(20));
    boost::scoped_ptr<int> pB(new int(20));

    boost::swap(pA, pB);
}
```

But it should be clear that this won't work:

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

int main()
{
    int* pA = new int(10);
    int *pB = new int(20);

    boost::swap(pA, pB);

    delete pA;
    delete pB;
}
```

Because `boost/scoped_ptr.hpp` has not provided (and indeed doesn't have the responsibility to provide) a general implementation of `boost::swap`. If you want to use `boost::swap` *in general*, you must include `boost/swap.hpp`:

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/swap.hpp>

int main()
{
    int* pA = new int(10);
    int *pB = new int(20);

    boost::scoped_ptr<int> pC(new int(20));
    boost::scoped_ptr<int> pD(new int(20));

    boost::swap(pA, pB);
    boost::swap(pC, pD);

    delete pA;
    delete pB;
}
```

Like that. If you have Boost available to do, do not fall back to the using `std::swap` stuff.

Answer (score 5):

This comes down to the swap idiom, or how swap should be implemented by user code. The recommended way of implementing `swap` for a type `T` in namespace `N` that has a set of members `m1`...`mN` is:

```
namespace N {
    void swap( T& lhs, T& rhs ) {
       using std::swap;
       swap( lhs.m1, rhs.m1 );
       ...
       swap( lhs.mN, rhs.mN );
    }
}
```

The idiom takes advantage of ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup). It first injects the definition of `std::swap` into scope, so that it is available when no better overload exists to *swap* a particular element. It then uses unqualified free function `swap`, knowing that if the type `Tn` of any of the `mn` members defines a free function swap, ADL will bring it into scope *and* the specialized `swap` will be used rather than `std::swap`.

What the documentation is saying is that you should not call `ptr1.swap( ptr2 )`, but rather *unqualified* `swap( ptr1, ptr2 )` to swap *any* element including `scoped_ptr` objects, following the idiom above. That is, if you implement your swap as that, the `swap` function need not change because of a change in your member types, including whether a pointer is just a raw pointer or a `scoped_ptr`.

Comment: non-templates always have precedence over templates during overload resolution, so a namespace-scoped non-template swap will take precedence over both boost::swap and std::swap. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6115281/391104)

Comment: argument-dependent lookup (ADL), or argument-dependent name lookup [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)

Comment: Why not use `boost::swap` to swap the pointers? The entire point of its existence is to not have to do the using `std::swap` stuff.

Comment: @GManNickG: The quote actually provides a reason: *It is preferable because swap(scoped1,scoped2) can be applied generically* That is, the reason is not having to know that it is `scoped_ptr`, what namespace it was defined or whether it has an overloaded `swap` at all. If you are going to inject the knowledge of what is being swapped, the member function `scoped_ptr::swap` would suffice.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: What do you mean? Using `boost::swap(x, y)` requires no knowledge on what type `x` and `y` are. What the quote is saying is that `swap(x, y)` is preferable to `x.swap(y);`, it's only lacking `boost::` qualification because it's a Boost book. My point still stands: why not use `boost::swap` for you swapping? It enables ADL automatically internally, precisely so you don't have to do the `using` stuff.